# Can I listen to the clientWidth/clientHeight properties on a div?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says, can I add a listener to a div to get when the clientWidth and clientHeight values change?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly no. If the width of the div is determined by the window width however you can attach a resize event to the window and when that fires you can grab the size of your div directly.